# Bootstrap4 dependency PopperJs throws error on Angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack, popper.js

I just created a brand new [angular-cli](/questions/tagged/angular-cli) project
and ran `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta jquery popper.js --save`
and changed the **.angular-cli.json**'s related parts as below

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
```

however receiving the error below

```
10:2287 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../popper.js/dist/popper.js (popper.js?4b43:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4403042439558687cdd6:54)
    at Object.2 (scripts.bundle.js:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4403042439558687cdd6:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap 4403042439558687cdd6:25)
    at scripts.bundle.js:1
```

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: odd, I got it to work for me. are you using the latest cli? can you try reinstalling node_modules

Comment: The error must be somewhere else

Comment: @LLai `@angular/cli: 1.3.0 node: 6.11.2 npm: 5.3.0` did you changed the parts in **.angular-cli.json** if you did not you won't see the error in console.

Comment: yeah I have your exact scripts & styles. jquery@3.2.1 popper.js@1.11.1 bootstrap@4.0.0-beta

Comment: i am ot sure how much this will help but you can look at this  question on this [page](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) there is a question on how to add third party libs

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Looking at the docs at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/#js you can see that they import the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Note the naming: jquery.**slim**.min.js, **umd**/popper.min.js!

Therefore I used the following in my `.angular-cli.json`:

```
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
```

After that it seems to work now.

Comment: What do you have in your packages.json for jquery?  In my node_modules jquery folder I didn't have a jquery.slim.min.js.  Actually just found it in jquery 3.2.1

Comment: My package.json looks as follows for jquery:

`    "jquery": "^3.2.1"`

I have testet it with the full jquery version too, it seems to work also.
Only the **umd**/popper.min.js seems neccessary.

Comment: This also works in Aurelia when added to the prepend section in aurelia.json. If you are replacing the alpha it will likely replace tether.

Comment: This answer has 76 upvotes... the dev gave a snarky "RTFM"/close to a Github issue asking the same question 

Comment: Using jQuery-slim or not doesn't matter, but using the umd-version of popper.js fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I have used the "/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" file instead of bootstrap.min.js and seems to be working without referncing popper. Maybe it's inluced in the bundle.

Comment: @Attmik not all components need popper.js. See http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

For example: 
* Dropdowns for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js)
* Tooltips and popovers for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js) If you import not the umd version of popper the error occurs.

Comment: Using `/dist/umd` instead of `/dist` in popper dependency did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 51):

I had the same problem. My solution was **not** to import the dist-folder (./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js) but rather the umd-folder (./node_modules/popper.js/dist/**umd**/popper.js). Does not matter if you get the mini or normal version of the js-file.

Answer (score 3):

I can see that many people are struggling with adding and properly including Bootstrap 4 dependencies (jQuery, popper.js etc.). But there is a much easier solution in the form of https://ng-bootstrap.github.io.

ng-bootstrap provides *native* Angular directives written from the ground up. The positive consequence is that:
* you don't need to include and worry about jQuery, popper.js etc.
* directives provide APIs that "make sense" in the Angular world

For anyone trying to use Bootstrap 4.beta with Angular - ng-bootstrap just released its first beta which is fully compatible with Bootstrap 4.beta CSS

Comment: Much easier if you're using Angular, but not if you're using AngularJS...

Comment: Well, the question was about Angular and angular-cli so not sure why the AngularJS is being brought up here...

Answer (score 1):

If you work in Asp.net Mvc **umd** also do the thing.

As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839939/8497522 just add in BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/popper").Include("~/Scripts/umd/popper.js"));
```

except:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/popper").Include("~/Scripts/popper.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To run modal please change the target from "es2015" to "es5" in tsconfig.ts

```
"styles": [ "src/styles.css", 
            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" ], 
"scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js", 
            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found hints in answers above :

1)Include `popper.js` before bootstrap

2. Update the path to popper.js file.
   Using `/dist/umd` instead of `/dist`

The correct path to popper was in angular-cli.json file was

```
./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js
```