# popper.js in bootstrap 4 gives SyntaxError Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I tried install bootstrap 4, and included following links

```
<script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js" ></script>
<script src="libs/popper.js/dist/popper.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

But The following error occurs :

> Uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected token export

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I do not know, bootstrap file requires it

Comment: no I have used bootstrap but it never asked to me

Comment: last version asked

Comment: well If it is so then I will tell use CDN links

Comment: the proble is that I'm not supposed to use CDN links when uploud on market

Comment: moreover, I tried it now, but it does not helped

Comment: just shift proper js line before the bootstrap js and tell me

Comment: still gives the same error

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start try this out it may help you

Comment: there may can be some error in file or in linking it...and remember adding pooper js before bootstrap js

Comment: If you pay attention to my question, then you will see that I added popper before bootstrap file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use popper 1.12.0 with bootstrap 4.0 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694811/how-to-use-popper-1-12-0-with-bootstrap-4-0-beta)

Comment: I'don't know if it is useful but here there is a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694811/how-to-use-popper-js-with-bootstrap-4-beta

Comment: Yes, latest version requires it. I was fine without it using standard bootstrap types, but then happened when i tried to do bootstrap drop down.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I encountered the same issue if I use popper.js from CDN network like `cdnjs`.

If you observe the source code of `Bootstrap 4` examples like for example [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbars/) you can see that `popper.min.js` is loaded from:

```
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
```

I included that in my project and the error is gone. You can download the source code from

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js
```

and include in your project as a local file and it should work.

Comment: yes. You are right. I did copy and paste that code and the error disappears. The CDN does not specify any specific version of `popper.js`

Comment: Although it works, I think this is not the proper way, until BootStrap team updates its own code.

Comment: The above URL returns a not found error (404). I used https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js for Bootstrap 4.1.3 and this resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Using the technique suggested in this answer is like chasing a moving target. Right answer is provided by Marc and Zim.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work anymore. The error is gone, but the tooltip is the default HTML tooltip

Comment: CDN links are often treated like a silver bullet for these kind of things, but oftentimes the answer is that you just need to use a different .js file in the downloaded folder. In this case, it's the UMD version of the folder you need, as Marc and Zim point out.

Answer (score 296):

Just got this too and figured why it really happens. In case others get by here:

Check the readme.md "Usage". The lib is available in three version for three difference module loaders. In short: if you load it with the `<script>` tag then you must use the *UMD* version. You can find it in `/dist/umd`. The default (in `/dist`) is the *ESNext* (ECMA-Script) which can not be loaded using the `script` tag.

Comment: Thank you. Got rid of the error for me by changing to the umd file.

Comment: Changing the reference to the file under umd folder solved my issue

Comment: This should have been accepted answer. Awesome. Thanks so much for sharing.

Comment: Awesome for the fast help, thanks. I was wondering what this /umd and /esm folders are but Google does not give good results.

Comment: Though this sounds like a Thanks, me too answer, Please let me add, @Marc you are a lifesaver. My developers spent a good 3 days with this issue hanging fire on low priority. It got escalated to my care and here we are. Resolved in 3 minutes flat. Let me add, we truly do stand on the shoulders of Giants.

Answer (score 106):

Bootstrap 4 requires the UMD version of `popper.js`, and make sure the order is as follows:

```
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The UMD version is the only CDN link that removed the error.

Comment: Thanks mate!

Your ordering fixed my issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 22):

You can also add bootstrap.bundle.min.js and remove popper.js in your html.

Bundled JS files (`bootstrap.bundle.js` and minified `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`) **include [Popper]**(https://popper.js.org/), but not [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` included `popperjs`

Comment: best answer since it doesn't require use of additional Popper.js library at all

Comment: BEST ANSWER, THANKS

Answer (score 12):

Line 96 in README

#### Dist targets

Popper.js is currently shipped with 3 targets in mind: UMD, ESM and ESNext.

- UMD - Universal Module Definition: AMD, RequireJS and globals;
- ESM - ES Modules: For webpack/Rollup or browser supporting the spec;
- ESNext: Available in `dist/`, can be used with webpack and `babel-preset-env`;

Make sure to use the right one for your needs. If you want to import it with a `<script>` tag, use UMD.

Comment: Using the popper.min.js file located in the UMD directory resolved my issued when installing popper via npm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You have following code in Bundle Config
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/umd/popper.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

following code in layout html

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

This worked for me