# Angular 6 and Popper.js toggle not working

Tags: jquery, html, angular, angular6, popper.js

I am building an angular 6 app and I have a button toggle.

Everything loads fine but when I click on the button to open the menu I have the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null at
>   Object.applyStyleOnLoad [as onLoad] (popper.js:1199) at popper.js:2443
>   ...

So I went online and did some research and tried this [popper.js in bootstrap 4 gives SyntaxError Unexpected token export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459767/popper-js-in-bootstrap-4-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export/46460112) but it did not help. Even when I load the CDN it still does not work.

How do we get around this issue?