# How to access jquery from the render process inside the preload script on Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I configured the Node integration to false in my window because, as described in the documentation, disabling is a good practice.

I want to access the jQuery of my render process in my preload script, but I don't know How I can do this.

Is it possible to activate a modal (for example) after some event occurs in the preload script?

Link to my example code in Github: https://github.com/JhonatanRSantos/Sample

Comment: What is the purpose of accessing JQuery in preload script. Since this runs before loading the HTML document.  I there any requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Janith said, you don't need to use a preload script. Here is a working sample based on your Github repo :

Index.html - in HEADER part, modify like this :

```html
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
<script src="./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you have to use the path `./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js` or you will get an error in the console (see [popper.js in bootstrap 4 gives SyntaxError Unexpected token export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459767/popper-js-in-bootstrap-4-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export/46460112))

Index.html - FOOTER, add :

```html
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

Rename preload.js to index.js

index.js can be :

```
console.log('Preload.js');
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Open Boostrap Modal');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}, 5000);
```

and finally, main.js can be :

```html
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let createWindow = () => {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        center: true,
        resizable: false,
        show: false
    });
    win.setMenu(null);
    const mainUrl = url.format({ // https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true,
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')
      })
    win.loadURL(mainUrl);
    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        win.show();
        win.webContents.openDevTools();
    });
    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    });
};
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

I made a pull request to your repo to get changes.