# Bootstrap Modal is not executing properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement bootstrap login Modal functionality in my code, but the output is not showing screen is not showing it.
Here is the output to the screen
[image: Error screen]

The red box in the image is where I want my Login Modal to be shown.

I have tried using the inspect element, to check the issue with my code, but it is also not displaying it.

But it is showing this error

> popper.min.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Header files attached:

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Scripts -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ccd9cbb4a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
</head>
```

Login Modal Code:

```
  <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="content">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                                    <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Sign in</button>        
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: We're going to need a [mcve] here

Comment: Login Modal code:

Comment: Posible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459767/popper-js-in-bootstrap-4-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export

Comment: Possible duplicate of [popper.js in bootstrap 4 gives SyntaxError Unexpected token export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459767/popper-js-in-bootstrap-4-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)

Comment: no its not the possible duplicate, I read that post before posting it here

Comment: @SMAmmar14 did you change to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js` and the problem still persists?

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use the getbootstap link for popper js instead of cdn link

```
 <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js
"></script>
```