# Navbar-Toogle Bootstrap 5 not working (with Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, bootstrap-5, popper.js

my  console  show me  this  error , it's about popper js . this is  the  error , and  i think  because of that  my toggle  button is not working

scripts.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

export default Popper;

and this  is my html file  and   scripts

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active" *ngIf="!isUser">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="login">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active" *ngIf="!isUser">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="register">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active" *ngIf="isUser">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="profil">Profil</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active" *ngIf="isUser">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="products">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active" *ngIf="isUser">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="myproducts">My Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active" *ngIf="isUser">
            <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

```
   "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
```

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459767/popper-js-in-bootstrap-4-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export

Comment: can i  use this 20

You can also add bootstrap.bundle.min.js and remove popper.js in your html.

Bundled JS files (bootstrap.bundle.js and minified bootstrap.bundle.min.js) include [Popper]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `umd` version of the script because it's browser compatible. In the scripts, array try to replace:

`"node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"`

with:

`"node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"`

Comment: "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ] and  still not  working   :/